# Clicking on a tile and changing its color in libGdx

Tags: java, libgdx, tile

I'm trying to click on a tile and change its color. So far I have this:

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
            Vector3 click = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
            camera.unproject(click);
            Cell clicked = path.getCell((int)click.x, (int)click.y);
            clicked.getTile();
    }
```

Once `clicked` has its tile coordinates (assuming I did this correctly) I now want to draw a blue square on that tile. How would I do this? I have `testTile.png` in my assets folder if that helps. I have drawn other pictures to the screen using `batch.draw();`. If anymore information is needed please feel free to ask.

`path` is the TiledMapTileLayer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I will approach this problem is having a list of custom class storing the locations where the blue square needs to be drawn and the sprite which needs to be drawn. (Storing sprite in list will give you more flexibility) 
So basically in your render method you will draw these tiles in by looping the List.

Example code : (Could not think of a better name than SpriteMap)

```
public class SpriteMap {
   int posX;
   int posY;
   Sprite sprite;

   public SpriteMap(int posX, int posY, Sprite sprite) {
       this.posX = posX;
       this.posY = posY;
       this.sprite = sprite;
   }
   //ignoring getters
}
```

Let's say you have a list of SpriteMap in your class where you are going to render and also have access to the list in isTouched() method.

```
List<SpriteMap> spriteMapList = new ArrayList<SpriteMap>();
```

Now inside your isTouched

```
if(Gdx.input.isTouched()){
      Vector3 click = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
      camera.unproject(click);
      spriteMapList.add(new SpriteMap((int)click.x, (int)click.y, new Sprite(THE_BLUE_BOX_TEXTURE));
}
```

Now in your render method all you have to do is loop the list and draw each and every sprite from list from SpriteMap objects.

```
//Pseudo code inside render after batch.begin(); 
for(SpriteMap spriteMap : spriteMapList) {
    spriteMap.sprite().setPosition(spriteMap.posX, spriteMap.posY);
    spriteMap.draw(batch);
}
```

**NOTE** Re-use the blue box texture. Also make sure you draw blue box after you have drawn the map else it will get hidden behind the map.

**ANOTHER NOTE** The positions x and y from clicked may need to be adjusted for the sprite to be drawn on the exact tile. So do change that accordingly. I have directly used X and Y from click but you may have to change them.

Hope that helps.